# Connection string needed to Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, powershell, connection-string

I'd like to connect to our Azure Data Warehouse database to write PowerShell test results from Azure Analysis Services (AAS) to a SQL table, so it can act as an audit trail and have a variety of other uses.

My group has rejected using SSIS and SQL Linked Servers as a solution. The options open to us are PowerShell and Azure Data Factory (ADF).

Below are the values I have to connect to Azure Data Warehouse (ADW):

```
        ADW name:                      XXX-dev-adw99e99999.database.windows.net
        ADW Database:                  dev-adw
        Service account:               svcZZZZZ_dev@OurDomain.com 
        AAS server:                    asazure://westus.asazure.windows.net/YYYYYYYYYYY 
        AAS model name:                WWWWWW
        $CmdQuery:                     'select 1'
```

Running the following code:

```
$QueryResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ADWServerName -Database $ADWDatabaseName -Query $CmdQuery -Username 'svcZZZZZ_dev@OurDomain.com' -Password 'QQQQQQQQQ'
```

I get the error below during execution:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'svcZZZZZ_dev'.
At line:224 char:21
+ ... ryResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ADWServerName -Database $A ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-Sqlcmd : 
At line:224 char:21
+ ... ryResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ADWServerName -Database $A ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

The service account has tons of permissions. What specifically would my connection string look like to write to ADW in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

what I think is happening here - you are trying to login with Azure AD auth, but `Invoke-SqlCmd` doesnt support that yet. you could use other means of logging in, like [this one](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Connect-DbaInstance), example number 8.

Comment: I tried it with a SQL login and password and received the same error. This is a great website, BTW. 

Could it be any different because it's Azure Data Warehouse?

Comment: Turns out that is a separate PowerShell DLL library:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.9.65/